# Creating a python script from interactive snippets

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm cleaning non-delimiter commas from my csv files. I have 3 python snippets that work interactively to change the delimiter, replace the commas and re-instantiate the comma delimiter. After retesting I found this single script doesn't work, I'd like to have some feedback on the best-practices way to run these in a single script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# changes delimiter 
import csv      
reader = csv.reader(open("commas.csv", "rU"), delimiter=',')
writer = csv.writer(open("commas2.csv", 'w'), delimiter=';')
writer.writerows(reader)
quit()

# replaces commas with spaces           
s = open("commas2.csv").read()
s = s.replace(',', ' ')
f = open("commas3.csv", 'w')
f.write(s)
f.close()
quit()

# changes delimiter back to commas
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("commas3.csv", "rU"), delimiter=';')
writer = csv.writer(open("commas4.csv", 'w'), delimiter=',')
writer.writerows(reader)     
quit()
```

Comment: does this script work? `quit()` should exit your interpreter... most probably its giving you an error message without the `quit()` but then if you put the `quit()` there it terminates after the first snippet but doesn't actually do what you want it to

Comment: I retested it and right, it doesn't work. I was seeing files that were created by running the snippets individually. I'd welcome suggestions for edits.

Comment: I'm not writing and closing the successive files out properly. I'll try 'with open' next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well as you said you need to use a `with` statement to close all the files properly (well you dont **need** to but it is best practice):

```
import csv
with open("commas.csv", "r") as fr:
    with open("commas2.csv", "w") as fw:
        reader = csv.reader(fr, delimiter=',')
        writer = csv.writer(fw, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerows(reader)


with open("commas2.csv", "r") as fr:
    s = fr.read()
with open("commas3.csv", "w") as fw:
    fw.write(s.replace(",", " "))

# changes delimiter back to commas
with open("commas3.csv", "r") as fr:
    with open("commas4.csv", "w") as fw:
        reader = csv.reader(fr, delimiter=';')
        writer = csv.writer(fw, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerows(reader)
```

but you could do this with one pass over the file, since you have all the csv contents already in memory you can modify them cell by cell instead of saving them with a different delimiter then changing the delimiter back :

```
import csv

with open("commas.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    new_data = [] # new csv 2d array
    for line in reader:
        l = list()
        for cell in line: # go over every cell
            l.append(cell.replace(",", " ")) # replace commas then save it to new array
        new_data.append(l)

with open("commas2.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(new_data)
```

Comment: Thanks, everything I needed. It really moves me forward with some python concepts I was having trouble with.